# Show values instead of ids for multiple fields sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How do I resolve user IDs to user names for multiple fields in an SQLite query. I have 2 tables, "Tickets" and "Users". "Tickets" has the user IDs, "Users" links the ID to the user's name. So I have the query below, but how do I show the user names instead of the ID numbers in the "created_by" and "assigned_to" columns.

```
SELECT tickets.id, tickets.summary, tickets.created_by, tickets.assigned_to
FROM   tickets
```

I don't think joining is the solution as joining on one field leaves me with a problem with the other.

Comment: Thanks NTR. I am new to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to join them like this two different alias

```
SELECT tickets.id, tickets.summary, u1.name, u2.name 
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN users AS u1 ON tickets.created_by = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users AS u2 ON tickets.assigned_to = u2.id
```